# Problem with alleg42.dll / program crashes / Allegro & Codeblocks

Tags: allegro

I'm having a serious problem with allegro. The program should display random pixels on the screen and when I build and run it I get the following error message:

Below is the full code of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "allegro.h"

#define Text_Color_Red makecol(255,0,0)
int main()
{
    int ret;
    int color_depth = 32;
    int x;
    int y;
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    int color;

    //init allegro
    allegro_init();

    //install keyboard
    install_keyboard();

    //set color depth to 32 bits
    set_color_depth(color_depth);

    //init random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    //init video mode to 640 x 480
    ret = set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED,640,480,0,0);

    if(ret !=0)
    {
        allegro_message(allegro_error);
        return 1;
    }

    //Display string
    textprintf(screen,font,0,0,10,0,Text_Color_Red,"Screen Resolution is: %dx%d -- Press ESC to quit !",SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H);

    //display pixels until ESC key is pressed
   //wait for keypress
    while(!key[KEY_ESC])
    {
        //set a random location
        x = 10 + rand() % (SCREEN_W-20);
        y = 10 + rand() % (SCREEN_H-20);
        //set a random color
        red = rand() % 255;
        green = rand() % 255;
        blue = rand() % 255;
        color = makecol(red,green,blue);
        //draw the pixel
        putpixel(screen, x, y, color);
    }

    //quit allegro
    allegro_exit();
}

END_OF_MAIN()
```

Error message: AllegroPixels1.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Error signature: AppName: allegropixels1.exe    AppVer: 0.0.0.0    ModName: alleg42.dll
ModVer: 4.2.3.0    Offset: 0006c05c

I am using Windows XP inside a virtual machine under Parallels 7.0

Comment: Is the dll that you're using compatible with your compiler? Not all dll's are created alike. You might also try to comment out everything between allegro_init() and allegro_exit(). See if your program still crashes. If it does not then you know the problem is part of the commented out code. Then add code back in one piece at a time to determine where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Running the debugger pointed to the `textprintf` line being the culprit. You have an extra parameter `10` in there that should not be there. Fixing that solved the problem.

HOWEVER, there are other problems with the code:

1. You are using the old version of `textprintf` use the new version like so:

   textprintf_ex(screen, font, 0, 0, Text_Color_Red, -1, "Screen Resolution is: %dx%d -- Press ESC to quit !", SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);
2. You are not calling `acquire_screen()` before you draw to the screen and `release_screen()` after you are done drawing.
3. Most importantly, you are not having `main` `return 0` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your program line by line to find the exact line the crash happens. It's been a while since I've used Allegro, but from what I see this should work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Allegro 4.2 is painfully old. Allegro 4.4 is source compatible. Allegro 5 is recommended, but has a totally different API.

The likely culprits:

1. The DLL you are using is not compatible with your compiler. You cannot mix and match. You cannot use a 4.2.0 DLL with a 4.2.2 program. You cannot use a gcc-built assembly enabled DLL with a C-only MSVC build, etc.
2. Running inside a VM is not going to be very pleasant. In the very least, you should probably use `GFX_GDI` as the graphics driver and `set_color_depth(desktop_color_depth())`.